# Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. $A$ is in the Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that the $f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Here is my attempt:

First, prove that any open set E has the property that $f^{-1}(E)$ is Borel. This is true because the inverse image of open set is open under continuous functions.
Next, prove that all sets $F$ with the property that $f^{-1}(F)$ is Borel generate a sigma-algebra. To verify this, we can check the 3 basic characteristics of a sigma-algebra.
Finally we can conclude $f^{-1}(A)$ is Borel.

Does my attempt make sense? If not, what is wrong? Your comments will be much appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it's the good way to go. Now, write down the details.